Datadog how to join RUM events with logs
I know datadog RUM collects a series of events within a session, and datadog log collection can also group logs within a session. In my app, I initialize the RUM and log collection separately. I want to associate logs with RUM events within the same session. I see both RUM and log collection expose session_id. Will they generate the same session_id for the same session? If not what data can I use to join those 2 records?
I currently have these 2 blocks of code to initialize logs and RUM
datadogLogs.init({
  clientToken: '<DATADOG_CLIENT_TOKEN>',
  site: '<DATADOG_SITE>',
  forwardErrorsToLogs: true,
  sessionSampleRate: 100,
});


datadogRum.init({
  applicationId: '<DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID>',
  clientToken: '<DATADOG_CLIENT_TOKEN>',
  site: '<DATADOG_SITE>',
  sessionSampleRate: 100,
  sessionReplaySampleRate: 100,
  trackResources: true,
  trackLongTasks: true,
  trackUserInteractions: true,
  enablePrivacyForActionName: true,
});


Assuming you are referring to browser logs, RUM events and logs are automatically correlated. This requires that your browser SDK and RUM configurations are matching. The session ids will match across logs and RUM events.

Thanks, I see from the instruction, in order to make them correlated, I must match configurations between the RUM Browser SDK and Logs SDK. I just added the code I used to initialize both, is there any changes i need to make to match the configurations?

That should be enough. I can't tell from your question if you are experiencing issues with your configuration or just planning for a change. My suggestion is to test it out and see what happens.
